# Open ports on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

What are the following open ports for on Azure Service Bus?

- 8443 (is this for the Management API?)
- 17000
- 17007
- 18000
- 18007
- 19000
- 19007

I can find documentation on other port such as 9350-9354, 5671, 5672, etc., but not ones on the list above. I need to document these for a penetration test on a project.

Regards,
Morten

UPDATE: Below is a screenshot of the NMap scan of a Service Bus endpoint

[image]

Comment: Can't seem to find any documentation on those, indeed. What's telling you those ports are open?

Comment: Third party was performing penetration test and performed a port scan on one of my service bus endpoints. They raised a Low severity issue on this. I can explain some of the ports, but not the listed ones. I believe they used Nmap.

Comment: We have been given the same remark by a 3rd party which did a pen test.   I also can't find any resources on why those ports are open.

Answer (score 8):

Azure Service Bus is using two default ports: 443 (HTTPS) for management operations and fail-over if TCP port 5671 is not available. TCP port is used by default for transport operations. Management operations are HTTP based. Additional TCP ports are 9350 to 9354. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?view=azure-dotnet) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.transporttype?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Thanks, but the 2 article only adresses the ports I was familiar with. There is no mention of the ports listed in my post above - i.e. 17000-19007. There are plenty of articles describing the standard ports you mention.

Comment: I've never seen those ports.
Management is done over HTTP/S, so those are something else.