# Which ports should be open for AMQP connection in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: port, firewall, amqp, azureservicebus

I have found documentation on AMQP regarding the ports that it uses:

> Azure Service Bus requires the use of TLS at all times. It supports connections over TCP port 5671, whereby the TCP connection is first overlaid with TLS before entering the AMQP protocol handshake, and also supports connections over TCP port 5672 whereby the server immediately offers a mandatory upgrade of connection to TLS using the AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding creates a tunnel over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP 5671 connections.

And some more detail in other post:

> It supports connections over TCP port 5671 and over TCP port 5672. The server immediately offers a mandatory upgrade to TLS using the AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding creates a tunnel over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP 5671 connections.

What I did not quite understand is what is the difference between those two ports. Should both be opened at all time or is it just one of the that is required and the other is some fallback or it depends on the library that is used.

P.S. I use `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` library to connect

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734498/open-ports-on-azure-service-bus/50769269) was raised just recently. You don't need all the ports at the same time. If you can't use TCP, which is the default, then you'd neeed WebSockets. Saying that, with the management operations coming to the client soon, communication is done over HTTPS.

Comment: I hope we can open firewall to use Amqp over tcp directly, but I could not quite understand the difference between the two ports that are used. Do you have an idea or a reference where I can read about details on how the library is using these ports? Looks like the library uses 5671 but what is the other port for then_

Comment: As far as I know 5671 for TCP and 443 for websockets and management.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at the code of the library and it seems you are right. Though documentation says that 5672 is at least theoretically possible for some other type of connection or something.

Comment: You could [raise an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues) to ask for documentation clarification. I'm continuously doing that and having some help would be nice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Details can be found here.
http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-security-v1.0-os.html#toc

Port 5671 is for pure TLS connection (section 5.2.1). It is actually what most clients do now as far as I know.

Port 5672 is for plain TCP connection and TLS upgrade (section 5.2).

Service Bus client only supports pure TLS connection over port 5671. The service supports TLS upgrade over port 5672 if a client needs to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer seems like a good explanation. Guess I have to read about what a TLS upgrade is :)